# C++ Static Function: Put Inside or Outside Scope of Class?

Tags: c++, scope

Say I have a class as follows in a header file:

```
class A {
public:
    void foo();
}
```

The function `foo` needs to call another "helper" function named `bar`. Bar isn't needed anywhere else other than inside `foo`. Should it be defined statically outside the scope of `A`:

(source file)

```
static void bar() { ... }
void A::foo() {
    bar(); ...
}
```

or within the class?

(header)

```
class A {
public:
    void foo();

private:
    void bar();
}
```

(souce)

```
void A::bar() { ... }
void A::foo() {
    bar(); ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should only allow access to the internals of a class when necessary. Placing the function outside the class and restricting its scope--either as a static function or within an anonymous namespace, would be best. That way, you're not polluting the global namespace and you're not allowing unnecessary access to class internals.

For example, you can, in the class's cpp file, have:

```
namespace {
   void bar() {.....}
}
```

and that helper function is then available for your class methods in the same cpp file.

Static functions in the cpp file would also have file scope only, but I find the `static` keyword to be confusing when used that way.

Comment: The more hiding the better. I agree that the "static non-class" option is the most hiding option (except to the compilation unit of class A itself). The only exception IMO is if that function accesses static members of the class A, in which case it would be goo candidate for a static private class member of A.

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> Bar isn't needed anywhere else other than inside foo.

If so then `bar` should be a private member function of class `A` - there is no need to define `bar` in global namespace.

```
static void bar() { ... }  // not needed
```

instead use:

```
void A::bar() { ... } // <- bar should be private member function
```

Comment: It should be defined within the class even if the function doesn't really pertain to the general purpose/focus of the class?

Comment: I think so, it's helper function, but in this case you mention it's only needed in class `A`. On the other hand if it's needed in different class then you may consider moving it out to a utility class.